# Warning:Google Maps already loaded outside @googlemaps/js-api-loader

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, nuxt.js

I am trying to utilize AdvancedMarkerView of Google Maps API with @googlemaps/js-api-loader in Nuxt3 in order to create a map similar to the one found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/html-markers). 
I attempted to use the example code for Advanced Markers found in @googlemaps/js-api-loader, but the markers are not showing up on the map.

Here is example code:
https://github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader/tree/main/examples

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="canvas" ref="canvas" class="canvas"></div>
```

**TypeScript - maps.vue:**

```js
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

const map = ref<google.maps.Map>();
const canvas = ref<HTMLElement>();

const loader = new Loader({
   apiKey: *************,
   version: "weekly",
   libraries: ["places"],
});

const initMap = () => {
    loader.importLibrary('maps')
        .then(async ({Map}) => {
            map.value = new Map(canvas.value as HTMLElement, {
                center: { lat: 34.6937, lng: 135.5023 },
                zoom: 17,
                mapId: '**************',
            });
            const priceTag = document.createElement('div');
                priceTag.className = 'price-tag';
                priceTag.textContent = '$2.5M';
            const {AdvancedMarkerElement} = await loader.importLibrary('marker'); // Here is line186
            new AdvancedMarkerElement({
                map: map.value,
                position: { lat: 34.6937, lng: 135.5023 },
                content: priceTag,
            });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            // do something
        });
}

onMounted(() => {
      initMap();
})
```

A warning message is displayed:

```
maps.vue:186 
Google Maps already loaded outside @googlemaps/js-api-loader.This may result in undesirable behavior as options and script parameters may not match.
```

How can I modify the code so that the marker shows up on the map?

*PS:*

I created a sample code on codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-sun-4xzhnf?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: You must be loading the API somewhere else. But not in the code you shared.

Comment: The code that loads the API is not located elsewhere.
I likely encountered this error because I called "loader.importLibrary()" twice.
I would like to know how to  prevent  the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.
When I changed it not to use ref to load the map,
the marker was displayed on the map.

```
const map = new Map(canvas.value as HTMLElement, {...
```

```
new AdvancedMarkerElement({
             map,
             ...
```

However, the warning is still displayed, but I will try using the map for the time being.
Thank you very much.

Comment: for some reason AdvancedMarkerElement doesn't work with Vue ref, confirm that. I also facing the warning after switching from deprecated `load` to `importLibrary`. Were you able to find out the reason?

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't causing any problems. But the imports are just promises, so to avoid the message (and possibly get a tiny performance boost) you can do all your loader imports at once, using Promise.all:

```
const loader = new Loader({
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    libraries: ['places']
});

const importMaps = loader.importLibrary('maps');
const importMarker = loader.importLibrary('marker');

Promise.all([importMaps, importMarker])
  .then(
    () => console.info('Google Maps loaded with status ', loader.status),
    () => console.warn('Google Maps failed to load');
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular `ref`s break Google Maps in Vue for some reason (a `ref` will make whatever object you pass to it deeply reactive by utilizing a `Proxy` object).

You have to use a shallow `ref`:

```js
const map = shallowRef<google.maps.Map>();
```

The `Google Maps already loaded outside @googlemaps/js-api-loader` warning it from calling `importLibrary` twice. Despite this warning, things still seem to work as expected; I'm not sure how `importLibrary` is suppose to be used as it's not clear from the docs, and there is an open issue about this: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader/issues/837